# How to retrieve value of base64 string stored in a variable to Jenkins Extended E-mail Notification plugin

Tags: jenkins, base64, email-ext

I am saving buildTimeGraph as an image (png) file in jenkins. I wanted to embed this image and send it via mail using Extended E-mail Notification plugin. Build is triggered via ant scripts.

when using "CERTUTIL" in cmd and converting to base64. i am getting  two statements that says -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----   and -----END CERTIFICATE----- in the base64 string. i use filterchain > tokenfilter > replacestring from ant to remove these lines from string and save them back to a variable.

does anyone know how variable can be used in img src tag ?
I have attempted many combinations but, its not worked for me.
This is what it looks like. the value of $image1 can be seen in jenkins log when i echo them using ant. but, when using them in Extended E-mail Notification plugin. it just wont print.

```
 <img alt="Image 1" src="data:image/png;base64, $image1" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To reference an environment variable in Email-ext plugin, you need to use

`${ENV, var="image1"}`

Keep in mind that if an environment variable is created in your Ant build step, it will probably not exist in your Post-build actions (unless your Ant script creates a permanent system environment variable)

You would need to have your Ant script to write the variable to a file, and then use **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** to read the file and inject the variable. Then it will be available as a regular environment variable to Email-ext, to be used with the syntax I provided